# sonarqube scanner for msbuild can't exclude external libraries

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I've been trying for a number of days now to exclude some files from a sonarqube scan. I have tried editing the exclusions list in the sonarqube UI, and passing them as a /d:exclusions parameter to SonarScanner-start.bat but nothing is working. This is the file I'm trying to exclude : Content/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js. Sonarqube insists on reporting this as a critical bug in the UI, despite my best efforts. Please can someone let me know how I can exclude this from the analysis.

Comment: Do you confirm that you're analyzing with SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild?

Answer (score 0):

The name of the property is `sonar.exclusions` and I suspect if you set it like this it should work:

`/d:sonar.exclusions=**/bootstrap-datepicker.js`

There are some examples for patterns here:
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-Patterns

If this does not help, please, edit your answer to include the full command line of SonarQube.Scanner.MsBuild.